# Layout created in 4 inch screen gets messed up in 3.5 inch screen even when using Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, ios6, autolayout

I have a simple login screen. It looks fine on the 4-inch screen.

[image]

But when I run it in the 3.5-inch screen, as you can see the bottom part gets cut off.

[image]

I have Auto Layout turned on and below are the constraints that are set.

[image]

If I may explain a little further, I have 4 UITextFields. The first one(User ID) is aligned as Center Y alignment. And each UITextField below each other has Vertical Space constraint set. For the Button also, The Vertical Space is set with the UITextField above(Server). I understand that's the constraint that's causing the problem. But say if I remove that and add a Bottom Space to SuperView constraint instead, the button's gonna overlap the last UITextField.

I've gone through both parts of the tutorial on Auto Layout here on RW. I still have no idea how to correct this. How can I make this layout appear correctly in both screen sizes?

Thank you.

Comment: fixed the loginbutton position from bottom

Comment: When I do that, the button overlaps the UITextField

Comment: you need to redefine your all UITextField constraints..

Comment: You mean through code?

Comment: first you set degine for 3.5 inch and then check in 4 inch....

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. I already have defined the constraints for the UITextFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is pin everything to the top making sure it fits for a 3.5 inch screen.  As the screen expands there will be extra space at the bottom.

The better option is vertically space the elements evenly on both screens, this can't be done purely in interface builder though.  You would need to calculate vertical spacings in code and apply them in `updateViewConstraints`

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to calculate vertical spacings through code? I'm kind of clueless to start on working that part..